# How to securely perform private key operation in android application

Tags: java, android

I know that android Keystore can be used to do encryption/decryption of the data without exposing the private key.

But, in my android application, the data itself is a secret key and used to generate a result by running a custom algorithm (not just encryption/decryption). This means the secret key has to come in clear text in memory to execute those custom instructions.

What is the best solution to securely perform the custom operation so that secret key doesn't get compromised?

Comment: [An Android KeyStore can hold a secret key entry](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/KeyStore.html). I don't know what you mean by 'without exposing the private key': it can't do that. Only an HSM can do that.

Comment: @EJP Yes HSM is exactly what I want. But how to exactly implement it. I know there are some vendors which provide whitebox cryptography libraries which can secure keys and perform the operations without bringing back the key in its original state. But I just want to know if there is any alternate way possible (like creating HSM)